# Search: is:answer hasaccepted:yes returns questions

Tags: discussion, search

I am trying to search for an answer that is not accepted but where the question has an accepted answer `is:answer isaccepted:no hasaccepted:yes` but this returns questions instead of answers.

Maybe the search simply does not support this but using `is:answer` and getting questions just feels wrong: [is:answer hasaccepted:yes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:answer%20hasaccepted:yes)

Shouldn't the query at least returns nothing or an error?

Wouldn't this be a nice feature?

BTW: The same happens for `is:answer` in combination with `views, closed, answers, is:question` but not for `migrated, wiki`

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is no problem with `is:answer`. If you will write `hasaccepted` in search box, then it will search for **questions.**

See the tooltip for `hasaccepted` in *Advanced Search Tips*

[image]

Comment: Ah, thanks! I did not see the tooltip. Anyway it should return nothing because the query does not make sense.

Comment: @PiTheNumber - May be devs have set priority on search fields. E.g. if there are both field `is:answer` and `hasaccepted:` then search for questions. etc..

Comment: Yes, they did but that is wrong. For example `is:answer is:question` should return nothing but it returns all questions.

Comment: @PiTheNumber - the last determinator wins, this is by design.  ...would you prefer we show no results, and call the user an idiot?  Seriously, that's the alternative here, so we opted for last-wins.

Comment: @NickCraver - I assumed the same. But in [`hasaccepted:yes is:answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3Ayes+is%3Aanswer) questions win over answers.

Comment: @NickCraver Yes, I would prefer to let the user know that his input does not make any sense instead of returning something he did not expect. Imaging a calculator where 3 divided by 0 returns 3 instead of an error. If you start guessing what the user wanted you need to let him know. Show the results as they are, but add a message explaining which parameter was ignored and why.

Comment: Also the tooltip is not expected here. There should be a text informing about it or better make the tips expandable like the FAQ.